# When streaming a song, in what folder does the song get saved?

Tags: google-chrome, streaming, browser-cache, audio-streaming, temporary-files

When streaming a song, the song is downloaded and placed into a temporary folder on the computer, that much I know. However, while streaming the media file – mostly from Pandora – I have been searching for the song in the cache folder of Chrome and the temporary internet folders but have not found it at all.

Does anyone know where songs, streamed using Google Chrome, are temporarily downloaded to?

Note: I am well aware that permanently downloading a song that you are streaming is illegal, and I am NOT trying to do this. This question is purely for educational reasons.

Comment: It might not be saved at all.

Comment: Well, if i check the developers console on the "Network" tab, I can see the .m4a file is being downloaded. I just need to know where.

Comment: which Operating System are we talking about here?

Comment: OS = Windows 8 x64

Comment: Streaming means it may only be buffered in memory... So you're probably on a fruitless voyage of discovery.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the folder on:

> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\Media Cache

sort by data, you find segment of the mp3 file of 1024 byte. When you recognize which segments compose your song, open a cmd line DOS session and then copy them in binary mode:

```
copy /b f_00015b+f_00015c+f_00015d+f_00015e Mika - Stardust.mp3
```

It works. Just tried by myself.

Comment: This looks promising! However, I did as you told me, but I can't seem to find any similar files in my Media Cache folder while streaming. In the folder, I can only see 5 files: "data_0", ..., "data_3" and "index". I have found some "fXXXXX" files with 2048 bytes in the "Cache" folder but no files with 1024 bytes.

Comment: Is it possible to alter this size from 1024 KB to some bigger size? Maybe if we could do it 10MB, no need to combine them in cmd then. 
btw - you anwered well.

Comment: B"H

Hello

Still works as a charm. Just open a command prompt and go to the Chrome cache folder (AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache), sort by date, and connect the latest files of 1024 bytes, in alphabetic order, using the copy /b command as indicated above.

Sincerely, Dovid.

Answer (score 3):

AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache

Sort by date time and probably the first file with reasonably larger size (3MB least) is your media, rename the file and append .mp3

EDIT : (Drag and drop the files into VLC player in case if you cant figure out what you're looking for)

There you go!

Answer (score 2):

Try NirSoft's [ChromeCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) which will display the contents of Chrome's cache folder:

[image: 1]

Comment: Will it show me where it is stored locally?

Comment: It should, or at least allow you to copy the file out. The cache folder is under your [user data dir](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory).

Comment: I've tried this program, but there are no audio files in the list. I've checked the header of the song and the content type is "audio/mp4", but there are no items in the list with this content type.

Comment: I'll also add, I'm mainly using pandora.com to stream the audio.

Comment: @Im2be you can get it even if you have the web-link.  create a minimalist `html` document with the `link` - `<html><body><a href="http://link/tomusic.mp3">download this!</a></body></html>` .  Open this `html` document in a browser.  Now, right click on the link and save it on your computer.  Hope this helps...

Comment: That's not the problem. You're talking about direct downloadable mp3-files. That's childs play. I'm talking about media (.ts, .ogg, .mp4 audio encoded) that is streamed to the browser and is being played using a JS library. The individual audio-clips HAVE to be loaded by the browser in order for the client (me, or rather my browser) to be able to stream the song. So in essence, the question is: where exactly in the OS this file is (temporarily) stored.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to this folder >>>> C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS\User Data\Profile 1\IndexedDB\https_www.pandora.com_0.indexeddb.blob\1\00
2. Right click on an empty space and sort this Folder by date modified
3. open the most recently modified file with notepad (If you ordered it descending from top to bottom it is the first file)
4. Press ctrl+F in the notepad to open a word search.
5. Search for the song name exactly as it is written or using a single word from it ie: Metallica's "stairway to Heaven", you can search for the word stairway and it should work fine. Make sure to press enter only **1 time** otherwise it will put you out of place.
6. Now search for the following text "audioURL"
7. Copy the URL that you see next to "audioURL" (URL will be on the right hand side). It is very long and usually goes onto the next line unless you have a large monitor. It typically ends with the following characters "3D%3D"

**Example**: (**NOTE**: *I replaced most of the characters with "X" and some numbers I replaced with "5" therefore your URL should consist mostly of characters liek this "LA4lsErlAUKf")* 
 https://audio-sv5-t5-5-vxvx.pandora.com/access/?version=5&lid=55555845&token=%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxevlE93zzllDc%2B8F1T2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxLA4lsErlAUKf9BvPl15gB%2F4ooVCgUKzy%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%2BeSMpyIJlkIgtsw%3D%3D

8. Paste the url into a web browser (*Microsoft edge will play the song but you cant save it. so use any other browser)* then either Use the download arrow on the media bar, or ctrl+s, or open the menu and find "save page as". It should save as an m4e by default.
9. Play the song on the Media player of your choice.
10. **OPTIONAL** Right click the file you saved and hit properties go to the "details" tab and fill in the song info.

Cheers :D

P.S. I'm a Necromancer (:

Comment: So for the part of "When streaming a song, in what folder does the song get saved?" are you answering that here too?